pulseaudio not launch in Ubuntu WSL
I compare my Native Ubuntu 22.04 and my WSL Ubuntu 22.04
I do "sudo apt install paprefs" on both side.
and I fix symbolic link in /usr/lib/pulse-15.99
then I do "ps -aux | grep pulseaudio" on both side.
I can see "/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no" at native Ubuntu but not in WSL
Then I manually lauch /usr/bin/pulseaudio at WSL side and got the following error
josephw@NV-JH12T34:/run/user/1000/pulse$ /usr/bin/pulseaudio
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Failed to open PID file '/run/user/1000/pulse/pid': Too many levels of symbolic links
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
I found /run/user/1000/pulse/pid is a symbolic link in WSL but it is a file in Native Ubuntu.
Then I temporary remove pid symbolic link and try again. and got different error
E: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-esound-protocol-tcp".
E: [pulseaudio] stdin-util.c: pa_module_load() failed
in this case, pulseaudio run but no sound.
I go to /etc/pulse and check the config file.  I don't see I tried to load module-esound-protocol-tcp.so
Anyone know how to make /usr/bin/pulseaudio running properly on WSL?
My goal is to use WSL as server not client.  I want the VM in the cloud pay music on my WSL.
Thanks

I give Ubuntu 24.04 a try and the symbolic link issue is gone.  But I still get Failed to open module module-esound-protocol-tcp.so
